# Return all dates between two dates as a list in flutter date range picker

Tags: flutter, daterangepicker

I got only two dates form flutter date_range_picker but I want a list of date between two selected dates. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Could you please show us the code you're using currently? (Show us only the relevant part.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following :

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    List<DateTime> days = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
      days.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
    }
    return days;
  }
```

Comment: as @henry2man suggested below, this solution falls over on some edge cases.

Comment: @Pablito what edge cases?

Comment: @genericUser it fails during the switch from the summer time to winter time in autumn and spring

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem with the accepted solution. The code will run fine most of the time but it will fail because this doesn't considers **Daylight saving time (DST) / Daylight time / Summer Time** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

As a result, for example it will generate the following sequence (notice the gap):

```
2020-10-24 00:00:00.000
2020-10-25 00:00:00.000
2020-10-25 23:00:00.000 # Mind the Gap :)
2020-10-26 23:00:00.000
```

Here it is an alternative solution that will work better, I think.

```javascript
List<DateTime> getDaysInBeteween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    List<DateTime> days = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
      days.add(
        DateTime(
          startDate.year, 
          startDate.month, 
          // In Dart you can set more than. 30 days, DateTime will do the trick
          startDate.day + i)
      );
    }
    return days;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Always use UTC** to avoid issues like DST when working with dates such as addition or subtraction and then convert them back to local time.

Also, adding days manually like `day + 1` could cause issues if both the start and end dates are not of the same month.

So to avoid all that do it like this:-

**Case 1 - Get days in between including start and end Date:-**

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBetweenIncludingStartEndDate(
    {required DateTime startDateTime, required DateTime endDateTime}) {
  // Converting dates provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on dates
  DateTime startDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(startDateTime.year, startDateTime.month, startDateTime.day);
  DateTime endDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(endDateTime.year, endDateTime.month, endDateTime.day);

  // Created a list to hold all dates
  List<DateTime> daysInFormat = [];

  // Starting a loop with the initial value as the Start Date
  // With an increment of 1 day on each loop
  // With condition current value of loop is smaller than or same as end date
  for (DateTime i = startDateInUTC;
      i.isBefore(endDateInUTC) || i.isAtSameMomentAs(endDateInUTC);
      i = i.add(const Duration(days: 1))) {
    // Converting back UTC date to Local date if it was local before
    // Or keeping in UTC format if it was UTC

    if (startDateTime.isUtc) {
      daysInFormat.add(i);
    } else {
      daysInFormat.add(DateTime(i.year, i.month, i.day));
    }
  }
  return daysInFormat;
}
```

**Case 2 - Get days in between excluding start and end Date:-**

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBetweenExcludingStartEndDate(
    {required DateTime startDateTime, required DateTime endDateTime}) {

  // Converting dates provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on dates
  DateTime startDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(startDateTime.year, startDateTime.month, startDateTime.day);
  DateTime endDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(endDateTime.year, endDateTime.month, endDateTime.day);

  // Created a list to hold all dates
  List<DateTime> daysInFormat= [];
  
  // Starting a loop with the initial value as the next day of the Start Date
  // With an increment of 1 day on each loop
  // With condition current value of loop is smaller than end date
  for (DateTime i = startDateInUTC.add(const Duration(days: 1));
      i.isBefore(endDateInUTC);
      i = i.add(const Duration(days: 1))) {

    // Converting back UTC date to Local date if it was local before
    // Or keeping in UTC format if it was UTC

    if (startDateTime.isUtc) {
      daysInFormat.add(i);
    } else {
      daysInFormat.add(DateTime(i.year, i.month, i.day));
    }
  }
  return daysInFormat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do like this:

```
final today = DateTime.now();
final monthAgo = DateTime(today.year, today.month - 1, today.day);

final List<DateTime> days = [];
for (int i = 0; i <= today.difference(monthAgo).inDays; i++) {
  days.add(monthAgo.add(Duration(days: i)));
}
```

Comment: as @henry2man suggested below, this solution falls over on some edge cases.