# DateRangePicker - Grey out unavailable dates

Tags: flutter, daterangepicker

As the title suggests I am using DateRangePicker to add date ranges to an array. If possible I would like to be able to "grey" out already selected dates in the array. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to returning the dates in-between the range in case anyone else needs it.

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBetweenIncludingStartEndDate(
    {required DateTime startDateTime, required DateTime endDateTime}) {
  // Converting dates provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on dates
  DateTime startDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(startDateTime.year, startDateTime.month, startDateTime.day);
  DateTime endDateInUTC =
      DateTime.utc(endDateTime.year, endDateTime.month, endDateTime.day);

  // Created a list to hold all dates
  List<DateTime> daysInFormat = [];

  // Starting a loop with the initial value as the Start Date
  // With an increment of 1 day on each loop
  // With condition current value of loop is smaller than or same as end date
  for (DateTime i = startDateInUTC;
      i.isBefore(endDateInUTC) || i.isAtSameMomentAs(endDateInUTC);
      i = i.add(const Duration(days: 1))) {
    // Converting back UTC date to Local date if it was local before
    // Or keeping in UTC format if it was UTC

    if (startDateTime.isUtc) {
      daysInFormat.add(i);
    } else {
      daysInFormat.add(DateTime(i.year, i.month, i.day));
    }
  }
  return daysInFormat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send disabled dates into the component.

[Check this sample of the documentation](https://flutter.syncfusion.com/?_ga=2.25036282.1922904524.1664746945-1450915158.1664746945&_gl=1*19m2kf6*_ga*MTQ1MDkxNTE1OC4xNjY0NzQ2OTQ1*_ga_WC4JKKPHH0*MTY2NDc0Njk0NS4xLjEuMTY2NDc0Njk3OS4wLjAuMA..#/date-range-picker/blackout-dates).

For further options, check [the whole docs](https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-daterangepicker#:%7E:text=Overview,dates%20to%20restrict%20date%20selection.).

Comment: OK, from what I can tell this accepts single dates. So say I have two dates to create a range. 1st October and 7th October, is there an easy way to get the individual dates in between so that I can enter those in the blocker to create the date range as un-selectable?

Comment: The answer to that should be un this post! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362685/return-all-dates-between-two-dates-as-a-list-in-flutter-date-range-picker