# hello i need to compare 2 dates like start date and end date and if i select a wednesday i need all wednesdays occuring between these dates

Tags: flutter, dart, date, comparison

I have a scenario where user selects a start date and end date and user also selects a specific day I need to show that specific day with date that occurs between them.

I tried the Intl package difference method but did not work

Comment: Please, provide an example about how it should work so we can better understand your requirement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method. Takes the start and end date and also the weekday. Note, can pass in 3 as an int or 'DateTime.wednesday' as the argument.

[Note, idea based on mirkancal's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362685/return-all-dates-between-two-dates-as-a-list-in-flutter-date-range-picker)

```
List<DateTime> getAllDatesOfAWeekday(
    {required DateTime startDate,
    required DateTime endDate,
    required int weekday}) {
  List<DateTime> allDates = [];

  for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
    if (startDate.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == weekday) {
      allDates.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
    }
  }
  return allDates;
}
```